# Apache does not run

Tags: apache, gitlab

I have a Centos 7 server with the names of one to play and another to use with Apache. Everything works correctly until I enable https for both domains. As of this moment, apache will not know if you have enabled the gitlab server.

-I get the following to the journalctl -xe exercise:

```
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                                    
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat                                                                                                               
--                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- A new session with the ID 1806 has been created for the user root.                                                                                                                      
--                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- The leading process of the session is 21782.                                                                                                                                            
sep 25 17:54:07 centOS sshd[21782]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)                                                                                        
sep 25 17:54:07 centOS systemd[1]: Started Session 1806 of user root.                                                                                                                      
-- Subject: Unit session-1806.scope has finished start-up                                                                                                                                  
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                     
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                                    
--                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- Unit session-1806.scope has finished starting up.                                                                                                                                       
--                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- The start-up result is done.                                                                                                                                                            
sep 25 17:54:07 centOS systemd[1]: Starting Session 1806 of user root.                                                                                                                     
-- Subject: Unit session-1806.scope has begun start-up                                                                                                                                     
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                     
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                                    
--                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- Unit session-1806.scope has begun starting up.                                                                                                                                          
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS polkitd[488]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:21855:10383292 (system bus name :1.3661 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fsep 25 17:54:32 centOS systemd
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up                                                                                                                                          
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                     
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                                    
--                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.                                                                                                                                               
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS httpd[21861]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80                                                                     
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS httpd[21861]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80                                                                  
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS httpd[21861]: no listening sockets available, shutting down                                                                                                         
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS httpd[21861]: AH00015: Unable to open logs                                                                                                                          
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE                                                                                       
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS kill[21863]: kill: cannot find process ""                                                                                                                           
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1                                                                                             
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.                                                                                                                 
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed                                                                                                                                                  
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                     
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                                    
--                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.                                                                                                                                                          
--                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- The result is failed.                                                                                                                                                                   
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.                                                                                                                
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.                                                                                                                                   
sep 25 17:54:32 centOS polkitd[488]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:21855:10383292 (system bus name :1.3661, object path /org/freedesktoplines 5302-5347/5347 (END)
```

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, which is about coding Q&A. Sounds like you need https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the port 80 is already in use from an other application. Go to your httpd.conf file in Apache and try to change to port `Listen 80` just to find out if thats the issue. Tell me if this works.

Change from:

```
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
```

To:

```
Listen 8012
ServerName localhost:8012
```

Enter: http://localhost:8012 in browser to check if this works for you.

Comment: Changing the port to 8012 has not worked.
I do netstat -punt and I do not see that port 8012 is being used by any service.

When I disable the ssl cetificado in gitlab apache it returns to run with nomality.????

Comment: Ah okey can you check if port 443 is already in use? It's the SSL port for your application.

Comment: Port 443 (ssl) is being used by apache.

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/error-98address-already-in-use-make_sock-could-not-bind-to-address-0-0-0-080-on-ubuntu-solved/

Comment: Solved had the duplicate listem entry in the httpd.conf file.                            Thanks for your help